# Fedora 20 and Windows 7 can't create partitions

Tags: windows, fedora

I have installed Windows 7 SP1 on my laptop. I have 4 partitions:

1. System reserved (Primary partition) 100 MB
2. C (Primary partition) 70 GB
3. D (Logical drive) 150 GB
4. E (Logical drive) 175 GB

I have 2 primary and one extended partition with 2 logical drives.

When I tried to install Fedora 20 automatic partition failed. And I tried to install manual partition. I am only able to create one partition. When I tried to create second partition it says error "not enough space". I think it's the problem of partition table. Windows only allows 3 primary partition. But I have only 2 primary partition. 
Any idea what's happened?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions, not general computer or operating system support. The [help] pages have more information about the types of questions that are appropriate here. There are other [se] sites that may be more suitable, such as [su] or [unix.se] - be sure to check the help pages for each site before posting there to see if your question is within that site's guidelines.

Comment: Am sorry .. i will try it other forums..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by installing windows 7 first with only one partition ie. C: . Then installed Fedora 20 and rebooted into windows 7 . Using disk management i created other two partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You already have four partitions which is the maximum for a "basic" disk under Windows.  You would have to destroy one of your primary partitions to create space to install Fedora.  Windows has a way of supporting more partitions "dynamic disk" but this isn't compatible with Linux.